# What to check first 400 Bad Request or 404 Not Found?

Tags: http, httprequest

For example, this `users` table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |

If I make an update request `PUT http://{host}:{port}/users/1` and supply correct json body

```
{
    "name": "John Roe"
}

Response (200) 
{
    "message": "Update Success"
}
```

It will return success request

And `404 Not Found` for request like `PUT http://{host}:{port}/users/3` with correct JSON body

And `400 Bad Request` for request like `PUT http://{host}:{port}/users/2` with incorrect JSON body like

```
Json Body:
{
    "name": ""
}

ErrorResponse (400):
{
    "message": "name is required"
}
```

But if i make a wrong request on no resource request like `PUT http://{host}:{port}/users/3` and with incorrect JSON body

what do i return, is it `400` or `404` check first?

Comment: Which do you expect to see as a response - 404 or 400?

Comment: 404 (?) but the content of the request is invalid at the same time

Comment: Any framework with strong mapping between requests and models will probably respond with a 400 (or 422) before even entering the controller. That aside, how you handle it is up to you if you're writing the backend

Comment: @DavidYappeter my point was - it's subjective, pick whichever you as an API designer like more.